# Failed to add a node to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I make the changes but
I can't add more than 2 nodes its will freez but if 1 or 2 node will work well what is the reason??? I gave_up 
I can do nothing for that
This is my code till time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct info{
    int num;
    char name[15];
    struct info *next;
};

struct info *first,*current,*new_s;
int struct_num;
void add_struct(void);

int main(){
    first=NULL;
    add_struct();
    puts("done");
    add_struct();
    puts("done");
    add_struct();
    puts("done");

    return(0);
}
```

//struct add function

```
void add_struct(void){

new_s= malloc (sizeof(struct info));
if(!new_s){
    puts("error");
    exit (1);
}
if(first==NULL){
   first = current= new_s;
   first->next = NULL;
}else{
    current=first;

    while(current->next!=NULL){
        current=current->next;
    }

    current->next=new_s;
    current=new_s;
}

struct_num++;
}
```

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: using a [sentry node](http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1) helps you avoid all special cases, such as empty list, first node, last node etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is

```
if( first==NULL){
first->next=new_s;
```

if `first` is NULL, you should **not** dererefence it. It is logically wrong, and invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

I think, what you want instead, is something like (pseudo-code)

```
if(first == NULL){
    first = new_s;
    first->next = NULL;
```

That said,

```
    current->next=new_s;
    current=new_s;
```

also looks problematic. The second statement there is wrong and not required, rather, you can add something like

```
   current->next = new_s;
   current->next->next = NULL;
```

Finally, your `struct_num` variable should be *global*, as per the current usage.

Note:

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
3. Always check for `malloc()` success before using the returned pointer.

Comment: i make the changes but when i try to make a list from 3 node or more its freez ,2 node work well, what is the reason ???

Answer (score 0):

Function `add_struct` is wrong 
For example if first is equal to NULL then you may not write

```
    first->next=new_s;
```

Take into account that there is no any sense to declare local variable of the function `struct_num` because it is always destroyed after exiting the function and moreover it even is not initialized in the function.

```
int struct_num;
```

If you need a count of nodes in the list then place it outside the function.

The function itself can look the following way

```
int struct_num;

int add_struct( void )
{
    new_s = ( struct info * )malloc( sizeof( struct info ) );

    if ( new_s == NULL ) return 0;

    // initialize data members num and name of the allocated structure
    new_s->next = NULL;

    if ( first == NULL )
    {
        first = new_s;
    }
    else
    {
        current->next = new_s ;
    }

    current = new_s;
    ++struct_num;

    return 1;
}
```